# SQL Server 2008 R2 which DB is default

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server Configuration Manager, I have 2 SQL Servers :

`SQLEXPRESS` and `MSSQLSERVER`, how can I know which one is the default ?

I have more questions

I have created a new database called TEST with a new table called test1

In visual web developer I am adding new data connection , in the server name dropdown , after I refresh, only one server appears, why ?

And in the database name I have nothing.

[image: in sql server configuration manager i have 2 servers , but when i am trying to add a connection only one server appears, why ?]

Comment: in sql server configuration manager i have 2 servers , but when i am trying to add a connection only one server appears, why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two instances of SQL Server running on your machine - you just specify which one you want to connect to in the server name box.  The "default" will be the instance listed as MSSQLSERVER which you connect to by just specifying your machine name or "localhost" in the server name box.

Comment: THANK U SO MUCH , MY PROB IS SOLVED

Answer (score 1):

You can run multiple instances of SQL Server on a given machine and indeed you can connect to multiple instances simultaneously via SQL Management Studio. The above answer is accurate that when you connect to the local machine by name you will default arrive at the Full SQL Server instances MSSQLSERVER if you intend to connect to the SQL Express instance you'll need to qualify the server name with the instance as MachineName\SQLEXPRESS or if its running locally localhost\SQLEXPRESS.

The qualification of the instance name can be used for other instances of MSSQLSERVER if you have further instances supplied e.g. MachineName\INSTANCENAME. You can individually stop instances either from the Services Applet where you'll find either SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) or SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) listed and you'll no longer be able to connect.

You can also use the SQL Server Configuration Manager to administer your instances, expand the Services node and see which instances are listed stopping the ones that are no longer relevant to you to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

well i guess you can only connect to one server at a time in your server explorer.
the server showing in your list is the one you have connected to.
have you created your database in the same server to which you are currently connected?

Comment: but both are running , so how can i stop one and connect to other one ?

Comment: have you set username and password while intalling?

Comment: for MSSQLSERVER i have a username and pass but the other one was automatically downloaded with visual web developer express edition

Comment: i guess you have also installed SQL server while intalling Visula WebDeveloper, if yes? you need to uninstall one instance of sql server because you cannot have two instances of SQL Server running on one machine.

Comment: if u see this link  , u see that u can have two server running and open connection with both of it      http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLrxFXXeLFk

Comment: yes it does, i am not sure how, as in never tried,
but the simple thing is, two instances always create problems for you, try removing the instance that installed with Web Developer.

Comment: ok , i will try to do this and i will get back to u , thank u